# Calibration of LSV models to vanna/volga break-even

Tags: equities, stochastic-volatility, calibration, local-volatility, vanna-volga

In this paper, [Labordère](https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=949097084122118080122097012069087091032013032038091020066027106007021091010006125022049012018120037051097086107093125094121101009005008019049003103030105071106103050046045083030001100102065070010114109127092089126110012099107086112098073027101024003&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE), the author computes a probabilistic representation of the the vanna/vomma(volga) break-even levels. He mentions that they can be used to calibrate LSV models to historical vanna/vomma BE. Does anyone know how can you do that? and why would you calibrate your model to these BE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pls provide more details about your question so that it can still be understood and answered in case the link to the paper is broken or changed.